# Vector space and abstract algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

For some fixed number $k$, let $W$ be a set of all real valued functions for which $f(6) =k$. Are there any values of $k$ for which $W$ will be a subspace of $F[a,b]$ with $a\le 6 \le b$?